# How can I open a .cat file?

Tags: cat, catalog

I'm looking for a way to open a .cat file. I have not a single clue about how to do it (I've tried with the notepad and sublime text, without results), the only thing I know is that it's not corrupted (it's read by another program, but I need to see it with my eyes to understand the structure of the content and create a similar one for my purposes).
Every hint is well accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make sense of it in a standard text editor, it's probably a binary format.

If so, you need to get yourself a program capable of doing hex dumps (such as `od`) and prepare for some detailed analysis.

A good start would be trying to find information about Advanced Disk Catalog somewhere on the web, assuming that's what it is.

Comment: I looked for what I get on sublime text, and it's as you said hex.
I tried with various dumpers, but I don't get anything that makes sense.
(also, ADC gives me "error 6" with the .cat that I'm trying to open and also with all the others)

Comment: @tabris963, then they may not be ADC files, that was just the most likely given the info available. You need to investigate what they are, work out the file format, and go from there.